# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, mysql, easyphp

I'm trying to have PHP (EasyPHP) connect to MySQL. Both are on my Windows laptop. I run PHP using Eclipse as IDE.

The PHP line that should make the connection looks like this:

`mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","DB_name");`

When I run the PHP code, I get the following message:

`Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target     machine actively refused it.`

I know there are multiple entries on StackOverflow that mention this problem, but they all seem to occur on complex client-server configuration. Mine is simple: a single laptop, so I hope there is a simpler solution than what has been suggested so far.

Anyone any suggestions? Thx in advance.

Comment: Maybe because you are not giving a DB user and password?

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting a couple of parameters

```
$rs = mysqli_connect("host","user","passwd","database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($rs));
```

Comment: Aren't the "user" and "passwd" optional fields? I didn't use them to keep everything as simple as possible.

Comment: How else are you going to authenticate with the database server?

Comment: Should I use the login and password for windows? It's the only login/password combination that's used on my laptop.

Comment: How do you connect to MySQL normally?

Comment: Don't know. This would be my first connection

Comment: There must be a database user setup on the mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

I found very simple way o resolve this error. The error comes because mysql db expects a tcp connection i.e ip address and not a string 'localhost'. so if u change your function to :

```
$dbhost = '127.0.0.1:3306';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

it will work fine.